# Spark - Shell - start up issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Getting below exception while trying spark-shell in windows. Is it really required internet to work?

```
C:\Users\hadoop>spark-shell
2018-09-27 06:50:30 WARN  Utils:66 - Your hostname, hadoop-8XUGY resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 2001:420:5249:1300:3514:e670:fb36:49f1 instead (on interface wlan2)
2018-09-27 06:50:30 WARN  Utils:66 - Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
2018-09-27 06:50:30 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native- library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
2018-09-27 06:50:37 ERROR SparkContext:91 - Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Expected hostname (not IP) but got 2001:420:5249:1300:3514:e670:fb36:49f1
        at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.checkHost(Utils.scala:982)
        at org.apache.spark.util.RpcUtils$.makeDriverRef(RpcUtils.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:164)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:500)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2493)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:933)
```

Comment: No, you do not need the internet for spark-shell to work. From the looks of it, this is about your loopback address being resolved incorrectly. Sadly, I am no expert of how loopback address resolution works in Windows.

Comment: @suj1th . still it is  blocking me to work

Answer (score 0):

Your logs are pointing to the issue. Notice this particular line:

```
   Your hostname, hadoop-8XUGY resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 2001:420:5249:1300:3514:e670:fb36:49f1
```

And when you execute spark-shell command, the scala assertion failed:

```
Expected hostname (not IP) but got 2001:420:5249:1300:3514:e670:fb36:49f1
```

There are two things that you can do. First, try to add following in your host file.

`::1             localhost`

Secondly, pass configuration directly using `--conf spark.driver.host=localhost`

> spark-shell --conf spark.driver.host=localhost

Answer (score 0):

check if the ipconfig to FQDN mapping (and vice versa) are resulting to the same machine.